# Unable to display French content properly in XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am using XmlDocument to create the xml in java.  I set database values as node text.  However, when I try

> doc.createTextNode("Some French content")

... it's not working.
The code runs, but I dn't get the French content properly.
While writing xml to file, I'm using UTF8.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it's not working" and "don't get the French content properly."  What exactly is happening?  What are you seeing?  How are you verifying the correctness of the XML?

Answer (score 0):

try to encode it in "ISO-8859-1 " instead of UTF8

If you put code you have written to create a XML, I can help better.